# Licenseplate formatting & validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a blackout... I haven't got a clue how to apply the javascript to the text area...
Also; what is best? Load it using onfocus, onblur or onclick?

I have a text area like this:

```
<input type="text" name="c_Kenteken" id="invoerKenteken" class="zoek_kentekenplaat" />
```

And this script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetSidecodeLicenseplate(Licenseplate){

var arrSC = new Array;
var scUitz = '';

Licenseplate = Licenseplate.replace('-', '').toUpperCase();

arrSC[0] = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{2}[\d]{2}$/         //   1       XX-99-99
arrSC[1] = /^[\d]{2}[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/         //   2       99-99-XX
arrSC[2] = /^[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{2}$/         //   3       99-XX-99
arrSC[3] = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/     //   4       XX-99-XX
arrSC[4] = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{2}$/     //   5       XX-XX-99
arrSC[5] = /^[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/     //   6       99-XX-XX
arrSC[6] = /^[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{1}$/         //   7       99-XXX-9
arrSC[7] = /^[\d]{1}[a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{2}$/         //   8       9-XXX-99
arrSC[8] = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/     //   9       XX-999-X
arrSC[9] = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}[\d]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/     //   10      X-999-XX

//except licenseplates for diplomats
scUitz = '^CD[ABFJNST][0-9]{1,3}$'              //for example: CDB1 of CDJ45

for(i=0;i<arrSC.length;i++){
    if (Licenseplate.match(arrSC[i])) {
        return i+1;
    }
}
if (Licenseplate.match(scUitz)) {
    return 'CD';
}
return false;
}

function FormatLicenseplate(Licenseplate,Sidecode) {

Licenseplate = Licenseplate.replace('-', '').toUpperCase();

if (Sidecode <= 6) {
        return Licenseplate.substr(0, 2) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(2, 2) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(4, 2)
}
if (Sidecode == 7 || Sidecode == 9) {
        return Licenseplate.substr(0, 2) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(2, 3) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(5, 1)
}
if (Sidecode == 8 || Sidecode == 10) {
        return Licenseplate.substr(0, 1) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(1, 3) + '-' + Licenseplate.substr(4, 2)
}
return Licenseplate
}
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
    input.zoek_kentekenplaat
{
    border:none;
    border-color:#F0F0F0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 30px; /*background-color: #f4be04;*/
    padding-left: 20px; /*border: 1px solid #ffcc00;*/
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: url(http://email.allianz.nl/public/ANG/278b2c33c92f75d6795b0c75e3a18e21/kenteken_125_2_2.jpg) no-repeat; 
    /*margin-bottom: 21px;*/
}
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jazperader/676sD/

I got the distinct feeling that it's just something tiny and stupid.
I know there isn't a onfocus, onblur or onclick in the text area HTML.

I'd like your expert opinion on this ;-)
Thanks!

Jazper

Comment: Are you trying to apply the formatting to the text area as the user types or when they are finished typing?

Comment: @Dropzilla: nicest is to have it applied as they type, but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is common, however, it brings up some performance concerns. Since you would ideally like to have the formatting applied as they type what you could do is use the keydown or keyup event so something like:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Again, this would fire every time the user typed and removed their finger from the key. So you are potentially creating a performance issue since the event will fire frequently. In your situation it may not be a big deal since you are only dealing with a small amount of text so the event may only fire 10 times or so.

If you do want to optimize your code a bit have a look at this http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/ You will see an example of how to throttle your events so your code is not executed every time.

Comment: I can't seem to call it right... what would you insert between the quotes if you take the functions from the script?

Comment: I noticed in your fiddle code there seems to be some errors. For example having $this as the first parameter of the first function is wrong. Also you have script tags in a weird place. Once you tidy up the code you should be able to do something like `onkeyup="GenerateLicenseplate(' + this.value + ', '+ GetSideCode(' + this.value + ')' + ');"`

Comment: I cut and pasted it wrong... here's the latest... http://jsfiddle.net/jazperader/676sD/32/

Comment: using the jshint button in fiddle I noticed that var arrSC = new Array was causing an issue. You can just declare the arrary literally by `var arrSC = []` Here is an updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/akpNR/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/akpNR/1/) Also I've updated the way values are passed into the onkeyup event. I've thrown in some alerts so you can see you are now making it to the functions, I'll leave it up to you to determine what to do next. Hope this helps.

Comment: <borat>Great Success!</borat> - It works! I made it a onblur, as this works perfectly for the form it is used in. In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jazperader/676sD/45/ you can see what I did. Thanks for all your help!